# ArcGIS Server 10.1 GP Service non-functional after ArcSDE restart

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase

every night, the Oracle/ArcSDE server gets restarted. As a result, some, but not all, map and GP services require a restart to be functional afterwards. Can others confirm this experience and share solutions?

at 10.0, when publishing a service, there was an option for the service to check for this sort of thing and repair itself, but this seems to have disappeared at 10.1.

failing and other feedback, we propose to automate the restart of all ArcGIS Server services after the nightly ArcSDE restart.

Comment: Does the GP service return an error?

Comment: errors vary by service, but are usually something like you'd expect - invalid layer, can't connect to the db... mainly in asking this I wanted to get other's experience. we currently DO stop/restart our services, but perhaps too soon after the db is cycled, before it is 100% back up?

Answer (score 5):

Tearing a database out from under an application is a fairly traumatic operation.  Since you do this each night, you should stop the AGS instance(s) before stopping the database, then restart after the database has been up for a minute.

Comment: Agreed best practise.  Startup scripts can be implemented to include either dependencies on other services (Oracle) already being started, or include delays in the startups to ensure Oracle has started ok before AGS kicks in.